# Tool to integrate JMeter reports with Jira/Zephyr

Tags: jmeter, jira, jira-zephyr

In our company, we use a framework for test automation created with Jmeter.

All the test cases are loaded by .csv files in Jmeter and then executed: The results are written in a separated .csv file.

After this, I have to import the results file into excel so I can create statistics and reports.

I'm looking for a tool that can import the csv files and create statistics automatically (better if web-based). A tool that integrates with Jira/Zephyr would be great - something that directly integrates JMeter output into Jira/Zephyr and links the results to test cases would be perfect.

**Are there any tools that can integrate JMeter with Jira/Zephyr, and if there are, what are their advantages and disadvantages?**

Answer (score 0):

Jira has buch of REST APIs you can use to create a task after your performance test and attach what ever you want (i.e jmeter results) to the task.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a tool that can import the csv files and create statistics automatically (better if web-based)

1. Since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30/) it's possible to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of .jtl/.csv result file
2. There is [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) online JMeter (and more) results analysis service.

> Are there any tools that can integrate JMeter with Jira/Zephyr, and if there are, what are their advantages and disadvantages?

1. Jira has [web APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/) so you should be able to perform any operation you need by sending simple [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to the JIRA API endpoints. 
   There is [Runscope Zapier](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002131738-Zapier-Integration) which can integrate with a lot of external services including but not limited to Jira, Bitbucket, Github, Trello, etc.

Comment: thanks, Dimitri, unfortunately, I've got this message: We apologize, some problem has occured during request processing
Our system said these words:

    403 Forbidden

    New users can be added only by invite from an existing user